# What is meant by "shorter connections" in the case of deep convolutional neural networks?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

Consider the following two excerpts from the research paper titled [Densely Connected Convolutional Networks](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Huang_Densely_Connected_Convolutional_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf) by *Gao Huang et al*.

#1: From abstract

> Recent work has shown that convolutional networks can be substantially
> deeper, more accurate, and efficient to train if they contain **shorter
> connections** between layers close to the input and those close to the
> output.

#2: From discussion

> One explanation for the improved accuracy of dense convolutional
> networks may be that individual layers receive additional supervision
> from the loss function through the **shorter connections**. One can
> interpret DenseNets to perform a kind of “deep supervision”.

Both excerpts mention the type of connections called shorter connections, especially to the layers that are close to the input and the output layers of the deep convolutional neural network. What does it mean by **shorter connections** here?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of those vague terminologies used in the context of skip (long-range connections). In a standard feedforward network, say if the information needs to propagate from layer 1 to 4, it has to go through two intermediate layers, namely $1 \to 2\to 3\to 4$. In a densely connected convolution network, every layer is connected to every layer downstream, meaning that you have a **direct** connection from layer 1 to 4, or $1\to 4$, hence a "shorter connection".

Note you also have other "shorter connections" such as $1\to 3\to 4$ and $1 \to 2 \to 4$

Answer (score 0):

Shorter connections are nothing but concatenating output tensors along the channel axis. Having shorter connections between layers, will help in gradient flow throughout the network easily and hence better training.